# Reading binary data from .raw image file formats

Tags: c, image, input, file-io, binary

I have an image which is in .raw file format and are stored as binary data. The image has 5 bytes of header which specifies information in the following order:

[image header format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DU9L.png)

Question now is, I want to write a simple program to output this image data as a 2d array so I can perform some simple image manipulation such as edge detection. I also want to output the header so I can double check if the header information is consistent with the information that I have for the image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    //specify filepointer
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("fruit.raw", "rb");
    //check if file is opened successfully
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error while opening file");
    }

    char c;
    while (1){
        c = fgetc(fptr);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

With my limited knowledge of C, I wrote this simple program and the code compiles successfully but I am not getting any output at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, by using "%c" as format specifier, you treat each byte of the image as an ASCII character, which probably isn't what you intended. If you use "%x" instead, you'll essentially get a hexdump of the file (which still might not be what you want). That being said, if the image isn't extremely dark, you should at least get some output

Comment: unfortunately, i have tried %x but it doesnt work as well

Comment: Are you sure the file gets opened correctly? Do you get the error message when you move it to another location? EDIT: EOF is equal to -1, so you should use int as the type for c, this might be causing your problem

Comment: fgetc() returns an integer not a character.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That image would be a good candidate to be added as text into the question.

Comment: You don't have characters from a text file. Don't treat is as you were. You should read binary data via `fread` into a buffer and extract the header fields.